# Custom CSS classes do not work in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hover

I have a custom section created for my WP page. You may find CSS and HTML here: http://www.cssdesk.com/J469A

I specified all the custom classes in CSS and added HTML via visual editor in WordPress, but the custom classes do not work, only HTML works.

You may have a look here: http://www.sflsupport.org/programs/ It's the very last section (Webinar Archive)

Comment: Is its Premium/Business ? Only Premium and Business accounts have access to add custom classes. Suurce https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/editing-css/

Comment: Yes, it's possible for me to add custom CSS as I am using WordPress.org not WordPress.com.

Answer (score 2):

You have added your styles incorrectly.

They have been added to a media query that is further up in your CSS and won't be applied unless your screen is 767px or less.

`@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)`

It looks like the media query is missing it's closing `}`.

Comment: You are right! You've just literally saved my life! Thanks a million!

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark this answer as correct if it has helped you.

Comment: Done! It's not displayed, though, cause I am a newbie here. Thanks so much again! :)